# Record Audio/Video with AVCaptureSession and Playback Audio simultaneously?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to create an iOS app which can record audio and video while simultaneously outputting audio to the speakers.

To do the recording and preview, I'm using `AVCaptureSession`, an `AVCaptureConnection` each for both video and audio, and an `AVAssetWriterInput` each for both video and audio. I basically achieved this by following the RosyWriter example code.

Prior to setting up recording in this fashion, I was using `AVAudioPlayer` to play audio.

Now, if I am in the middle of capturing (not even recording, just capturing for preview), and attempt to use `AVAudioPlayer`, my `captureOutput` callbacks on my `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` class stop getting called.

Is there a workaround for this?

Is there another, lower level service I should use to be playing audio that won't stop my capture?

mc.

Comment: The answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7219499/2700842

Answer (score 0):

You first set the `AVAudioSession` and its category. For example in `viewDidLoad` method,

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
```

Therefore you can play BGM

```
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:music_url error:nil];
    [self.player setDelegate:self];
    [self.player play];
```

and record the movie

```
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    /* ... addInput AVCaptureDeviceInput AVMediaTypeVideo & AVMediaTypeAudio */
    /* ... addOutput */
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *m_captureFileOutput =[self.captureSession.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
    [m_captureFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:saveMovieURL recordingDelegate:self];
```