# Audio Input and Output in same iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio

Okay so I am creating simple objects to later be used for audio input and output. Both objects work independently just fine, but when I try to use them in the same application, they clash and the audio input object  gets blocked out by the output object.

The output object is using AudioUnitSessions to pass samples into a buffer and play audio, while the input object is using AudioQueue to feed in samples from the microphone, which we can later process.

I think the solution is as simple as deactivating the AudioUnitSession, but this does not seem to be working. I am doing this the following way

```
AudioSessionSetActive(true) or AudioSessionSetActive(false)
```

above depends on whether I am trying to activate it or not.

Apparently this does not work because whenever I try to recreate the input object, it fails to initialize the recording with OSStatus error number -50.

Does anyone know of a way around this, or a simple way of audio input and output in the same application.

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184341/ios-sample-code-for-simultaneous-record-and-playback