# iPhone record audio from mic while playing music from iPod library using MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, mpmusicplayercontroller, audio-player

Is it possible while playing music from iPod library using MPMusicPlayerController, recording voice form mic on iPhone?
If possible, any sample or code?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184341/ios-sample-code-for-simultaneous-record-and-playback

Comment: @atrljoe, I cannot find playing iPod library music from the above link.