# iOS: Bad Mic input latency measurement result

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio, microphone

I'm running a test to measure the basic latency of my iPhone app, and the result was disappointing: 50ms for a play-through test app. The app just picks up mic input and plays it out using the same render callback, no other audio units or processing involved. Therefore, the results seemed too bad for such a basic scenario. I need some pointers to see if the result makes sense or I had design flaws in my test.

The basic idea of the test was to have three roles:

1. My finger snap as the reference sound source.
2. A simple iOS play-thru app (using built-in mic) as the first
   listener to #1.
3. A Mac (with a USB mic and Audacity) as the second listener to #1 and
   the only listener to the iOS output (through a speaker connected via
   iOS headphone jack).

Then, with Audacity in recording mode, the Mac would pick up both the sound from my fingers and its "clone" from the iOS speaker in close range. Finally I simply visually observe the  waveform in Audacity's recorded track and measure the time interval between the peaks of the two recorded snaps.

This was by no means a super accurate measurement, but at least the innate latency of the Mac recording pipeline should have been cancelled out this way. So that the error should mainly come from the peak distance measurement, which I assume should be much smaller than the audio pipeline latency and can be ignored.

I was expecting 20ms or lower latency, but clearly the result gave me 50~60ms.
My ASBD uses kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical and kAudioFormatLinearPCM as format.

Comment: Well 50 ms corresponds to a total buffer size of around 2048 at a 44.1 kHz sample rate, which doesn't seem unreasonable given that you have both a record and a playback path.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I didn't realize that the buffer size is 2048 by default. It would then make sense since 2048/44.1k means 46ms latency! Note I've found the way to change buffer size. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know that the buffer size is 2048, and there may be more than one buffer in your record-playback loopback test, but it seems that the effective *total* buffer size in you test is probably of the order of 2048, which doesn't seem unreasonable. Of course if you're only interested in record latency, as the title of your question suggests, then you'll need to find a way to tease that out separately from playback latency.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense now. By lowering the audio session buffer size property to 5ms, I'm now getting 17ms play-through latency, that's something I was expecting. Thank you for the answers. If you don't mind, I'll post your comments as the answer and mark it as correct, OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize Paul R's comments as the answer, which has solved my problem:

50 ms corresponds to a total buffer size of around 2048 at a 44.1 kHz sample rate, which doesn't seem unreasonable given that you have both a record and a playback path.

I don't know that the buffer size is 2048, and there may be more than one buffer in your record-playback loopback test, but it seems that the effective total buffer size in you test is probably of the order of 2048, which doesn't seem unreasonable. Of course if you're only interested in record latency, as the title of your question suggests, then you'll need to find a way to tease that out separately from playback latency.

Answer (score 1):

50 mS is about 4 mS more than the duration of 2 audio buffers (one output, one input) of size 1024 at a sample rate of 44.1 kHz.

17 mS is around 5 mS more than the duration of 2 buffers of length 256.

So it looks like the iOS audio latency is around 5 mS plus the duration of the two buffers (the audio output buffer duration plus the time it takes to fill the input buffer) ... on your particular iOS device.

A few iOS devices may support even shorter audio buffer sizes of 128 samples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use core audio and set up the audio session to have a very low latency.
You can set the [buffer size to be smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863330/adjust-the-length-of-an-audiounit-buffer) using `AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration,...`

Using smaller buffers causes the audio callback to happen more often while grabbing smaller chunks of audio.  Keep in mind that this is merely a suggestion to the audio system.  iOS will use a callback time suitable value based on your sample rate and integer powers of 2.

Once you set the buffer duration, you can get the actual buffer duration that the system will use using `AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration,...`